# AngularJS: Sorting ng-options which is an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can you sort the options in a `{select}` like this:

```html
<select ng-options="value as name for (value,name) in vm.options" ng-model="vm.selected">
```

when `vm.options` is an object (I want to sort by values)?

Context: At some point I needed to add an explicit empty option "" as a valid value. I'd love it to be the first one on the list, but due to how objects work in Javascript I can't get it to cooperate.

Comment: you cannot sort a object with `{key:value,key:value}` but you convert it to array and apply `| orderBy:'fieldName'`

Comment: You can't sort dictionary in Javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve in the following way

```
<select ng-options="option.value as option.name for option in vm.options | orderBy:'value'" ng-model="vm.selected"></select>
```

and if you want to add empty option like 'Select' then

```
<select ng-options="option.value as option.name for option in vm.options | orderBy:'value'" ng-model="vm.selected">
    <option value="" selected>Select</option>
</select>
```

Please also refer following link

['orderBy' in AngularJs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy#ordering-a-table-with-ngrepeat-)